# Why I cannot see CMake version from the terminal inside Visual Studio Code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmake, path

I installed CMake on Windows and I added the path to Sytem Variables (C:\Program Files\CMake\bin)

I can see it with from command prompt:

```
D:\>cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

But when I try to same from the Visual Studio Code's terminal, I get an error:

```
PS D:\Cmake\Mastering-CMake> cmake --version
cmake : The term 'cmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cmake --version
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cmake:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The CMake extension also reports an error:

```
The "cmake" command is not found in PATH.  Install it or use `cmake.cmakePath` in the workspace settings to define the CMake executable binary.
```

But I already added CMake to the Path. What else should I do? Thanks!

Comment: (In VS Code terminal) `PS ...> where.exe cmake` should output the path to CMake.

Comment: `PS ...> $env:Path -split ';' | Select-String '\bcmake\b'` should output the path to CMake, also.

Comment: If either of these commands fail, then you need to check the environment, or VS Code settings, or maybe reboot OS.

Comment: Did you add CMake to the path after you started Visual Studio Code? You may have to restart Code.

Comment: Actually, I have adjusted CMake path in `CMake configuration` extension (in settings). Besides, I have CMake path added into system PATH.

Comment: it works, after I added the CmakePath in the VSC extenstion and restarted the OS.. thanks Dmitry!

Comment: How to add the cmakepath in vsc extension?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio Code made it update the `PATH`.
New terminals can find `cmake` now.